# Android - how to point the emulator / device to use MacOS system hosts file?

Tags: android, macos, host

I need for the emulator to use the etc/hosts file on my mac. Is it possible to do that? Could I be pointed to links / blogs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[According to developer documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking) in the section titled "Configuring the Emulator's DNS Settings":

> On Linux and OS X, the emulator obtains the DNS server addresses by parsing the file /etc/resolv.conf. On Windows, the emulator obtains the addresses by calling the GetNetworkParams() API. **Note that this usually means that the emulator ignores the content of your "hosts" file (/etc/hosts on Linux, /private/etc/hosts on OS X, %WINDOWS%/system32/HOSTS on Windows).**

You can, however, tell the emulator to use a different DNS server (for details on this just keep reading on that same page I linked to above). You might just wanna setup your own little dns server and do all your ip address resolution through that.