# Accessing website with hostname hosted in IIS from android browser emulator

Tags: android-emulator

I have a website hosted under IIS

IP Address is= **(All Unassigned)** i.e no IP address is assigned to website when i check the properties of website.

e.g http://test.demo.com/xxx/xxx.aspx

A host name(e.g :test.demo.com) is given to the website and this host name is mapped to "127.0.0.1" in **hosts** file of windows.

when I tried to access the website using "http://127.0.0.1/xxx/xxx.aspx" in IE browser 
Server Error in '/' Application is displayed.The site is accessible only when accessed with hostname .

I have used **adb** commands to pull the host file from android ,changed 127.0.0.1 to 10.0.2.2 and pushed the altered file back again.

Tried to access the website it displays an error **WebPage cannot be dispalyed**

But from the post mentioned here in [Android - how to point the emulator / device to use MacOS system hosts file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7639034/android-how-to-point-the-emulator-device-to-use-macos-system-hosts-file)

I have opened the emulator from command line by passing DNS server also

Since this is the website hosted in IIS in the same machine i dont need connectivity to internet/intranet.

When I am trying to access the same website from BlackBerry simulator it was also not resolving the hostname and displaying error "Server Not Found"

Can anyone give me a solution of resolving Hostname to IP address in android emulator and blackberry simulator